# How to convert equations from one variable to another

Tags: linear-algebra

I have three to five 4th order polynomial equations solving for y as a function of x; but each equation is at a different value of a third variable, z.  Is there any way that I can extract an equation that solves for y as a function of z at a fixed value of x?  I believe that the actual form of the solution I seek will be linear; i.e.

y = mz + b at a fixed value of x.  But m and b will change if x changes.  If I don't need to make the linear assumption, that would be better.

The equations are simply 4th order polynomial fits to the curves generated by the experiment (6th order polynomial fits are slightly better). Below is an example of the curve fits from an experimental run.

At a value of z equal to $5\times10^{-12}$:
$$y=3\times10^{34} x^4 {-} 8\times10^{30} x^3 + 9\times10^{26} x^2 {−} 4\times10^{22} x + 7\times10^{17}$$
At a value of z equal to $1.58\times10^{-7}$:
$$y=2\times10^{30} x^4 {-} 7\times10^{26} x^3 + 8\times10^{22} x^2 {−} 4\times10^{18} x + 6\times10^{13}$$
At a value of z equal to $1\times10^{-2}$:
$$y=4\times10^{25} x^4 {-} 1\times10^{22} x^3 + 1\times10^{18} x^2 {−} 6\times10^{13} x + 1\times10^{9}$$

How should I go about trying to get the solution for y as a function of z at a fixed value of x?

Comment: Please show the equations.  Otherwise we simply cannot help.

Comment: Show these equations.

Comment: As requested, sample equations are now included.